# not able to install EntityFramework.SQLite on asp.net core RC1 project

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, asp.net-core, dnx

I want to develop an API for my Raspberry Pi by using Windows IoT as OS.
IoT only supports ASP.NET CORE for the moment, so I'm stuck with that.

When I try to add the SQLite package through Nuget I get the following error:

> Package 'EntityFramework.SQLite.7.0.0-rc1-final' is not found on source 'https://www.myget.org/f/aspnetmaster/api/v3/index.json'.

Honestly, I've got no idea where to look for this problem. 
Here are some random stats about my project:

global.json:

```
{
  "projects": [ "src", "test" ],
  "sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.0-rc1-update1"
  }
}
```

project.json:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "compilationOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNet": "1.0.0-rc1",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileProviderExtensions": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-rc1-final"
  },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel",
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { },
    "dnxcore50": { }
  },

  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "publishExclude": [
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ]
}
```

DNX Version:

```
dnx --version
Microsoft .NET Execution environment
 Version:      1.0.0-rc1-16609
 Type:         Clr
 Architecture: x86
 OS Name:      Windows
 OS Version:   10.0
 Runtime Id:   win10-x86
```

Comment: NuGet CI, release and master feeds moved to nuget.org. They're no more on myget. Changed your nuger.config

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following. What do you suggest I should do to make it work?

Comment: update your nuget.config your are pointing to an old NuGet feed : 'https://www.myget.org/f/aspnetmaster/api/v3/index.json'. Use https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json instead. Upgrade your dependencies version and switch to dotnet-cli instead of dnx

Comment: if you still  want to use the rc1, the package is availabe there : https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.SQLite/7.0.0-rc1-final.

Comment: Okay thank you, I'll test that when I get home. But I've got a good feeling about the answer ;)